# JavaFX CSS button background with image | no path |

Tags: css, button, javafx

Im getting too much problems with CSS files path finding. So I use this form:

```
button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(160,160,220); -fx-background-radius: 50%;");
```

How to add image background for button, without image overriding text?

Answer (score 0):

By using :

```
  button.setStyle ("-fx-background-image: url('file:///w:/Task.jpg');");
```

Typing `file:///` is very important to have correct pathfinding.
**(w:)** is hardrive disk. More common to have **(c:)**.